# Какие могут быть последствия из-за принудительного добавление тега script в React

Tags: reactjs

Стояла задача, добавить в проект написанный на react - emarsys. Очень кратко: Отслеживание действий на сайте и формирование статистики. Среди npm пакетов не было готового пакета, который упростил бы жизнь и инициализировал ресурс в моем проекте. В свою очередь на проекте через useEffect (используем только хуки), в конец тела body добавил скрипт методом appendChild. Все отрабатывает, но меня посещают сомнения что так делать не совсем правильно, ибо общий бандл формируется webpack, и мой скрипт находится под этим бандлом. Какие могут быть последствия от такого жесткого внедрения в проект?

Comment: а почему не в index.html просто?

Comment: в react нет файла index.html

Comment: ух ты, открытие, однако... к чему же корневой компонент биндится? посмотрите public/

Comment: если ты говоришь про билд, то да, естественно там есть минифицированный html. Но если перечитать мой вопрос, то я так и делаю - добавляю script в тело body. Повторю вопрос  - Какие могут быть последствия от такого жесткого внедрения в проект?

Comment: я не про билд. просто посмотри в корень проекта, там есть public/index.html, туда и надо было вставить

Comment: да, верно. Тем или иным способом я сделал тоже самое. Все же вопрос остается открытым)

Comment: Если этот скрипт не меняет DOM, то ничего не будет, иначе могут возникнуть ошибки работы React